# Laravel Eloquent relationship where not in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I've viewed many answers for this and my code is working, but it's not producing the intended results.

I have a locations table and listings table. Many listings can belong to one location.

What I would like to do is get a specific location, and the result should include all connected listings except for the one that the user is viewing. I pass the `$listing_id` for to the subquery for this, but the problem is that the `$location_other_listings` still includes that listing (in the example below with `$listing_id = 3`).

```
$listing_id = 3;
$location_other_listings = Location::whereHas('listings', function ($query) use($listing_id) {
  $query->where('id', '!=', $listing_id);
})
->where('id', $location_id)
->first();
```

**Update:**

I tried the inverse as well (`whereDoesntHave` and `=` instead of `!=`):

```
$listing_id = 3;
$location_other_listings = Location::whereDoesntHave('listings', function ($query) use($listing_id) {
  $query->where('id', '=', $listing_id);
})
->where('id', $location_id)
->first();
```

But that produces NULL for all my different listings. Not sure why.

As indicated the first query works. So what I could do is: when `$location_other_listings` is empty I know there are no other listings connected. If it's not empty, I could remove the listing with the current `listing_id` from the result array. That would produce the desired result, however I was wondering if I can produce this result with one query.

Comment: You can always try to break your query, by using idd instead of id in the sub query, that way you will have the raw query, which makes solving this easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `with()` method with constraint https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads.

```
$listing_id = 3;
$location_other_listings = Location::with([
        'listings' => function($query) use ($listing_id){
            $query->where('id', '!=', $listing_id);
        }
    ])
    ->where('id', $location_id)
    ->first();
```

Then $location_other_listings->listings will not contain current listing with id 3.